# Confusion in Anonymous Method

Tags: c#

I have a class called Employee. in which there are three auto implemented properties and a function which is returning the employees names who git bonus salary, I am using delegates so there is no logic in this function and that is the reason this class and method is reusable.

```
class Employee
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Salary { get; set; }
        public static void BonusForEmp(List<Employee> emp, Bonus Isavailable)
        {
            foreach (Employee e in emp)
            {
                if (Isavailable(e))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Name + " got bonus");
                }
            }
        }

    }

     delegate bool Bonus(Employee Employes); // Delegate
```

Here It Is my Main method in which i create a list of employees and doing all the steps like creating a instance and passing the method as an argument.

```
List<Employee> EmpList = new List<Employee>();
            EmpList.Add(new Employee() { Id = 1, Name = "A", Salary = 12000});
            EmpList.Add(new Employee() { Id = 2, Name = "B", Salary = 7999 });
            EmpList.Add(new Employee() { Id = 3, Name = "C", Salary = 1999 });
            EmpList.Add(new Employee() { Id = 4, Name = "D, Salary = 20000});
            Bonus B = new Bonus(BonusAvailabeFor); //instance of dlegate and pasing method name as an argument
            Employee.BonusForEmp(EmpList, B); //using 
            Console.ReadLine();
```

So All of you thinking that where is my method(BonusAvailableFor) in which i did all the logical work which matches the signature of delegate? Here it is

```
 public static bool BonusAvailabeFor(Employee eml) // the function with same signature of the delegate here we use our logic.
        {
            if (eml.Salary > 8000)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

So this code is working so perfectly nice and returning the names of employee whose Salary > 8000.
I just read anonymous method somewhere that is inline expression that can be used wherever a delegate type is expected.They provide us a way to create instance of delegate without having to write a separate method .. the definition looks great it will reduce my lines of code if i can implement this in my scenario, so how can i achieved it ? <=== (My Question) 
well i know i can do this with Lambda expression or with FindAll() predefine funtion in list collection class , but i am here to do it with anonymous method ..

Comment: I don't understand why you don't just use the Any(e => e.Salary > 8000) method. I understand you don't want to use lambda but, why not?

Comment: C#2.0 doesn't support Linq or anonymous types, did you really mean to tag the question with that?

Comment: @stuartd are you sure?  In my knowledge Anonymous method were introduced in c#2

Comment: @Eduardo I just want to lear the concept of anonymous method thats Why

Comment: The `delegate` keyword was available in 2.0, which is effectively a lambda, but lambda syntax came in 3.x.

Comment: @KennethK. right

Comment: Well Microsoft have a great doc about that. It really just looks a lot like JavaScript way of doing it. Take a look: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/anonymous-methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understand your questions correctly, the `delegate` keyword has multiple uses. One use is to define a new delegate type; the other use is to create an anonymous method. The latter can be used in your example as:

```
Bonus B = delegate (Employee e) { return e.Salary > 8000; };
```

You can omit assigning to the variable and pass the anonymous method directly to the method:

```
Employee.BonusForEmp(EmpList, delegate (Employee e) { return e.Salary > 8000; });
```

...but that would make that line a bit verbose (i.e. unreadable). Personally, I'd leave it broken out.

Comment: This is what i was asking , Thankyou Genius :)

Comment: But one thing is confusing me here What is the purpose of this line
Bonus B = delegate (Employee e) { return e.Salary > 8000; };

Comment: Employee.BonusForEmp(EmpList, delegate (Employee e) { return e.Salary > 8000; }); 
  < ==  i was looking for exactly this line

Comment: The right side of the `=` is the anonymous method. The left side is capturing the method to a variable so you can pass it around. Like I said, you can omit capturing it, and just pass it directly to the method, but then you have the `delegate (blah blah)...` stuff jammed inline into your other lines of code. This can be hard to read.

Comment: This is exactly what's in Microsoft docs. I don't understand why you needed to make this thread since there's a perfect documentation about this.

Comment: Thakyou Got it now